# Как динамически внести в код картинку по смысловому содержанию?

Tags: php

Есть PHP-функция `<?php echo $this->product->product_gtin; ?>`. 
 Она вызывает определенное значение.
 Как сделать с помощью PHP, чтобы: 
если выводится слово "Россия", подставлять `<img class="product-manuf" src="/russia.png">`, 
если Беларусь - `<img class="product-manuf" src="/belar.png">`, 
если Америка - `<img class="product-manuf" src="/usa.png">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В дополнение ответов, хочу привести альтернативный вариант решения проблем, который, по моему мнению, будет более удобным для пользования и масштабирования. Вы объявляете массив значений и берете там то, что вам надо по ключу:

```php
$country = [
    'Россия' => 'russia'
    ...
];

echo "<img class='product-manuf' src='{$countr[$this->product->product_gtin]}.png'>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
switch ($this->product->product_gtin)
{
     case 'Россия':
         $src = 'russia';
         break;
     case 'Беларусь':
         $src = 'belar';
         break;
     .......
}
echo '<img class="product-manuf" src="/',$src,'.png">';
```

Answer (score 2):

А что мешает переименовать картинки "россия.png" "сша.png"

```
 echo '<img class="product-manuf" src="/'.$this->product->product_gtin.'.png">';
```